# Filter only MAX month figures Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of values for orders per month by region that looks like this:

**Orders Table**

| Orders (YTD) | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 2021 |
| 4 | Feb | 2021 |
| 4 | Mar | 2021 |
| 5 | Apr | 2021 |
| 14 | May | 2021 |
| 16 | Jun | 2021 |
| 17 | Jul | 2021 |
| 19 | Aug | 2021 |
| 22 | Sep | 2021 |
| 24 | Oct | 2021 |
| 34 | Nov | 2021 |
| 35 | Dec | 2021 |
| 1 | Jan | 2022 |
| 3 | Feb | 2022 |
| 4 | Mar | 2022 |

Along with a table that orders the months in sequence as below, that will be modelled to order the months in the first table so that they appear in sequence in graphs.

**Monthly Sequence Table**

| Month Sequence | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan |
| 2 | Feb |
| 3 | Mar |
| 4 | Apr |
| 5 | May |
| 6 | Jun |
| 7 | Jul |
| 8 | Aug |
| 9 | Sep |
| 10 | Oct |
| 11 | Nov |
| 12 | Dec |

Upon closer inspection of my data, I have realised that the number of orders per month are not the raw figure per month, but a cumulative total for every order in the calendar year so far (new orders for month + orders for preceding month). Firstly, I want to calculate the correct sum of orders per year, which should actually just be the MAX month from the orders table. Of course in most years this will be December, but for the current year it needs to be the latest month. I wanted to use a measure to calculate the MAX 'Monthly Sequence Table'[Month Sequence] number from each table, by year. I thought maybe a filter function would be used but could not work out exactly how to do this in DAX.

Secondly, and similarly, I want to calculate the actual number of orders per each individual month using DAX. In this case, I want to take the Orders (YTD) total for that month/year combination and subtract it from its immediately preceding month. What would the formula look like for this?

Thanks in advance.